# Thinking Question - Application of Vectors Grd 12 - Orthogonal and sum of Vectors

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

[Question 2][We received this thinking question but I've been very confused on how the sum of these orthogonal vectors relate to their orthogonality, not sure what to do here if someone could explain this that would be great!]

Mr. Eng was examining a problem with regards to orthogonal vectors. He let u, v, w  be vectors orthogonal to each other. He then performed the following

u + v

u + w

v + w

What can Mr. Eng say about the sums of these vectors? What can Mr. Eng say about the sums of these vectors with regards to their orthogonality? Explain and Justify your answer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoZZw.png

I initially assumed the resultant vectors would be orthogonal to each other with a 45º angle between the resultant and the original vectors u,v,w. However, after putting it through GeoGebra I saw the resultant vectors are not orthogonal but have an angle of 60º. What can I say about the sums of these vectors and their relations to their orthogonality?

Comment: Done @RossMillikan

Comment: Take the dot products of the sums.  If the sums are orthogonal the dot products will be $0$.  Note that we are only given that the original vectors are orthogonal, not that they are orthonormal, so one could be much longer than the other two.

Comment: How would I use the dot product to prove whether it's equal to 0 or not with only variables. @RossMillikan

Comment: You would use the fact that the original dot products were $0$.  Expand the dot products of the sums and you will get dot products of the original vectors.  Some of them will be vectors with themselves, which are not $0$.  Argue that you know the new vectors are not orthogonal, or at least may not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $(u+v)\cdot (u+w)=u^2+u\cdot w + v\cdot u + v \cdot w=u^2+0+0+0 \gt 0$ as long as $u$ is not the zero vector.  They are not orthogonal.  The same applies for any other pair.